# psycopg2.NotSupportedError: access method "gin" does not support unique indexes

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, peewee, jsonb

I am using python 3.5, peewee 2.7.4, and PostgreSQL 9.4.1.0 to create some models:

```
for model in models:
    print('creating {}'.format(model._meta.name))
    model.create_table()
```

I tried to put a unique parameter on one of the JSONB fields:

```
attrs = BinaryJSONField(unique=True)
```

However, when I try to create the table I get the following error:

```
psycopg2.NotSupportedError: access method "gin" does not support unique indexes
```

Do I have to implement my own unique function outside PostgreSQL for this use case or can I use a different access method?